# Correctly printing a binary tree sideways in C

Tags: c, binary-tree, pretty-print

I've been trying to make a function that prints a binary tree (in this case is a Red-Black tree) sideways in the console in a pretty way. I found this algorithm in the internet and adapted it to my project.

Note: I've seen a lot of ways to print a binary tree in Java here in SO and other websites but they were mostly using Java's String or some other high level language and in C sometimes it can be very hard to adapt the code. The code below is as close as I've gotten with printing a binary tree in a pretty way.

```
static void
rbt_display_treeview(Node *root, int depth, char *path, bool is_right)
{
    const int spaces = 8;

    if (root == NULL)
        return;

    depth++;

    rbt_display_treeview(root->right, depth, path, true);

    path[depth - 2] = 0;

    if(is_right)
        path[depth - 2] = 1;

    if(root->left)
        path[depth - 1] = 1;

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < depth - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == depth - 2)
            printf("%c", is_right ? 218 : 192);
        else if (path[i])
            printf("%c", 179);
        else
            printf(" ");

        for (int j = 1; j < spaces; j++)
            if (i < depth - 2)
                printf(" ");
            else
                printf("%c", 196);
    }

    printf(" %d\n", root->data);

    for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
    {
        if (path[i])
            printf("%c", 179);
        else
            printf(" ");

        for (int j = 1; j < spaces; j++)
            printf(" ");
    }

    rbt_display_treeview(root->left, depth, path, false);
}
```

The above code is called as:

```
// Red-Black tree is created and elements (int) are added

// Printing the tree
char *path = calloc(10000, sizeof(char));

if (!path)
        return;

rbt_display_treeview(tree->root, 0, path, false);
printf("\n");
free(path);
```

There are two problems though: This code will try to access the index `-1` of `char *path` when the node is root and there might be an overflow of `char *path` if the tree is really really big. So here goes my first two questions:

- **How to prevent this behavior when the node is root?**
- **How big should `path` be so that if the user tries to print a really big tree he will run out of stack space before overflowing the buffer?**

When I tested it I added the following integers in order in my red-black tree:

```
[ 16, -34, 24, 43, 18, 20, 22, -21, 4, 28, 45, 24, -47, -43, 29, 14, -35, 32, 8, -9, -46, 41, 46, -3, 17, -32, 24, 50, -19, -48, 15, 20, 22, -50, -43, 18, -28, 12, -14, 19, 12, 44, 19, 23, 45, -38, 45, -15, -28, 15, 35, 16, -41, -25, 7, -20, -7, -13, -31, -5, -48, -37, -23, -36 ]
```

And it produced the following output:

```
                            ┌─────── 50
                            │
                    ┌─────── 46
                    │       │
                    │       └─────── 45
                    │               │
                    │               └─────── 44
                    │
            ┌─────── 43
            │       │
            │       │       ┌─────── 41
            │       │       │
            │       └─────── 35
            │               │
            │               └─────── 32
            │
    ┌─────── 29
    │       │
    │       │       ┌─────── 28
    │       │       │
    │       └─────── 24
    │               │
    │               │               ┌─────── 23
    │               │               │
    │               │       ┌─────── 22
    │               │       │       │
    │               └─────── 20
    │                       │
    │                       │       ┌─────── 19
    │                       │       │
    │                       └─────── 18
    │                               │
    │                               └─────── 17
    │
     16
    │
    │                               ┌─────── 15
    │                               │
    │                       ┌─────── 14
    │                       │       │
    │                       │       └─────── 12
    │                       │
    │               ┌─────── 8
    │               │       │
    │               │       │       ┌─────── 7
    │               │       │       │
    │               │       └─────── 4
    │               │               │
    │       ┌─────── -3
    │       │       │
    │       │       │               │       ┌─────── -5
    │       │       │               │       │
    │       │       │               ┌─────── -7
    │       │       │               │       │
    │       │       │       ┌─────── -9
    │       │       │       │       │
    │       │       │       │       └─────── -13
    │       │       │       │               │
    │       │       └─────── -14
    │       │               │
    │       │               │       ┌─────── -15
    │       │               │       │       │
    │       │               └─────── -19
    │       │                       │
    │       │                       └─────── -20
    │       │                               │
    └─────── -21
            │
            │                               ┌─────── -23
            │                               │
            │                       ┌─────── -25
            │                       │       │
            │               ┌─────── -28
            │               │       │
            │               │       │       ┌─────── -31
            │               │       │       │
            │               │       └─────── -32
            │               │               │
            │       ┌─────── -34
            │       │       │
            │       │       │               ┌─────── -35
            │       │       │               │
            │       │       │       ┌─────── -36
            │       │       │       │       │
            │       │       │       │       └─────── -37
            │       │       │       │
            │       │       └─────── -38
            │       │               │
            │       │               └─────── -41
            │       │
            └─────── -43
                    │
                    │       ┌─────── -46
                    │       │
                    └─────── -47
                            │
                            └─────── -48
                                    │
                                    └─────── -50
```

But then I saw some lines that shouldn't be printed, like those below the numbers 22, 4, -7, -13, -15, etc. So I added the another condition in the last `for` loop to see if I could filter those unnecessary lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)
{
    if (path[i] && (root->left || i != depth -1)) /* Here */
        printf("%c", 179);
    else
        printf(" ");

    for (int j = 1; j < spaces; j++)
        printf(" ");
}
```

In fact it did, but I still don't know why. Also the two lines above the node `-9` are still being printed when they shouldn't be there. This is what I have so far:

```
                            ┌─────── 50
                            │
                    ┌─────── 46
                    │       │
                    │       └─────── 45
                    │               │
                    │               └─────── 44
                    │
            ┌─────── 43
            │       │
            │       │       ┌─────── 41
            │       │       │
            │       └─────── 35
            │               │
            │               └─────── 32
            │
    ┌─────── 29
    │       │
    │       │       ┌─────── 28
    │       │       │
    │       └─────── 24
    │               │
    │               │               ┌─────── 23
    │               │               │
    │               │       ┌─────── 22
    │               │       │
    │               └─────── 20
    │                       │
    │                       │       ┌─────── 19
    │                       │       │
    │                       └─────── 18
    │                               │
    │                               └─────── 17
    │
     16
    │
    │                               ┌─────── 15
    │                               │
    │                       ┌─────── 14
    │                       │       │
    │                       │       └─────── 12
    │                       │
    │               ┌─────── 8
    │               │       │
    │               │       │       ┌─────── 7
    │               │       │       │
    │               │       └─────── 4
    │               │
    │       ┌─────── -3
    │       │       │
    │       │       │               │       ┌─────── -5
    │       │       │               │       │
    │       │       │               ┌─────── -7
    │       │       │               │
    │       │       │       ┌─────── -9
    │       │       │       │       │
    │       │       │       │       └─────── -13
    │       │       │       │
    │       │       └─────── -14
    │       │               │
    │       │               │       ┌─────── -15
    │       │               │       │
    │       │               └─────── -19
    │       │                       │
    │       │                       └─────── -20
    │       │
    └─────── -21
            │
            │                               ┌─────── -23
            │                               │
            │                       ┌─────── -25
            │                       │
            │               ┌─────── -28
            │               │       │
            │               │       │       ┌─────── -31
            │               │       │       │
            │               │       └─────── -32
            │               │
            │       ┌─────── -34
            │       │       │
            │       │       │               ┌─────── -35
            │       │       │               │
            │       │       │       ┌─────── -36
            │       │       │       │       │
            │       │       │       │       └─────── -37
            │       │       │       │
            │       │       └─────── -38
            │       │               │
            │       │               └─────── -41
            │       │
            └─────── -43
                    │
                    │       ┌─────── -46
                    │       │
                    └─────── -47
                            │
                            └─────── -48
                                    │
                                    └─────── -50
```

- **How do I prevent those two lines being printed?**

P.S.: The red-black tree implementation is working just like any other red-black tree. You can also test this in other binary trees as I intend this code to run on any binary tree.

Comment: I once did something similar but not that nice looking and in C++: [SO: c++ delete specific node with two children from binary search tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48826108/7478597) (`struct PrintInT`). These pretty print algorithms are brain skrewing. I believe the essential difference in my case, I didn't store the path but the "indentation prefix". The reason was that nodes in path may be left children or right children of their resp. parent and have to be handled respectively. So, each node "knows" how to prefix children and simply adds this to its own prefix.